# Which is correct: "Below the targets" or "Behind the target"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, word-usage, syntactic-analysis

I am writing a letter to one of our customers and would like to inform him that he is still behind the targets and has got 3 weeks.

My employer has introduced this offer according to which they will give $0.5 per unit of the product purchased in excess of the target units.

so I would like to inform them about their current situation. here is my email. Please let me know if I am using *target* correctly.

> Hello XXX,
>
> Hope all is well.
>
> This email is in reference to our Special Incentive Program, Enclosed please find the copy of the contract for your reference.
>
> Your total purchase for this year is 1000 cartons, which is 200 cartons behind the target goal. Kindly note this program will end on Dec 23rd, and you will receive $0.5 per carton if your purchase is in excess of 1000 cartons on carton above 1000 units.
>
> I remain at your disposition for any further information you may require.

Comment: I would be a little reluctant to use "target" in this sense, when dealing with a customer.  They're apt to think the target is on their back.

Comment: Which is 200 short of the [first?, next?] incentive goal...

Comment: The target is a number to be reached: Below target. If the target is to reduce a number (like traffic accidents): Above target. The target is a date: You can be behind or ahead of the target.

Answer (score 1):

The common idiom for this would be that your customer has *fallen short of the target*. Reference is at http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fall+short+of

Answer (score 0):

> ... which is 200 cartons **below target**.

I've never used ngram before but here's a shot at it:

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=below+target&year_start=1940&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbelow%20target%3B%2Cc0

[image]

Comment: Using ngram is absolutely pointless because "below target" and "behind target" are each correct in different situations.